# Olympiad combinatorics problem (probably related to graph theory?)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

Let me state the problem first. The problem is from the 2017 Japanese Mathematical Olympiad.

There are $n$ people in the group, where $n$ is greater than or equal to 3. Each day, some people (more than or equal to 3 people) from the group have a social gathering. For each gathering, everyone who participated in the gathering shake hands with each other. After the gathering of $n$-th day, any two people among total $n$ people shook their hands exactly once throughout all gathering. Show that the number of people attending each gathering is constant.

I tried to formulate it in a graph-theoretical way. On the very first day, there are $n$ vertices and no edge. Then we start to add a "clique" in this graph. After $n$ such operations, the graph became a complete graph (with no duplicate edges). Now what we want to show is the size of each clique added is always the same.

Number of total edges in $K_n$ is ${n \choose 2}$. As we add each clique with the size $k_i$, we are adding ${k_i \choose 2}$ edges. So I assume that it can be formulated as: $${n \choose 2} = {k_1 \choose 2} + {k_2 \choose 2} + \cdots + {k_n \choose 2}$$ Then $k_1 = k_2 = \cdots = k_n$. However I am not sure about the correctness.

Both formulation do not give me a hint about how to approach this problem. I am not skilled in both graph theory and combinatorics.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is more like number theory :)

Comment: Are the total number of people and the total number of gatherings supposed to be the same $n$? Because this gives a restriction on $n$, it doesn't work out with $n=3$ or $n=4$.

Comment: @quarague Yes, they are the same $n$.

Comment: From his calculation we get ${n\choose 2}\geq 3n\implies n\geq 7$ @quarague

Comment: Suppose $A_{i}$ is the set of people gathering on day $i$. A couple of observations: Since no handshake occurs in more than one meeting, we have $|A_{i} \cap A_{j}| \le 1$ for all $i,j$. By the pigeonhole principle, that means $|A_{i}| \le n/2$ for all $i$.

Comment: Another necessary condition on $n$ (assuming the conclusion) is that $n-1$ can be factored as $k(k-1)$ for some $k$ - this $k$ is the number of people who gather on each day. In particular, $n$ must be odd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each person $P$, let $\|P\|$ denote the number of gatherings $P$ was part of. For each gathering $g$, let $\|g\|$ denote the number of people who participated in the gathering.

**Lemma.** If $P$ is not part of $g$, then $\|P\| \ge \|g\|$.

**Proof.** Let $\|g\|=k$ and let $P_1, \dots, P_k$ be the people who participated in $g$. For each $i$, there has to be another gathering $g_i$ where $P$ and $P_i$ shook hands; the gatherings $g_1, \dots, g_k$ must be distinct, because if $g_i = g_j$ then $P_i$ and $P_j$ shake hands twice (once in $g$ and once in $g_i$). Since $P$ participates in all $k$ gatherings $g_1, \dots, g_k$, we have $\|P\| \ge k = \|g\|$. $\qquad\square$

To make use of this fact, we want to number the people $P_1, \dots, P_n$ and the gatherings $g_1, \dots, g_n$ such that $P_i$ does not participate in $g_i$ for $i=1, \dots, n$. This is a perfect matching between the people and the gatherings, in the "nonparticipation" graph where an edge $(P,g)$ means that $P$ was not part of $g$. We check Hall's condition: for any set of $k$ people, there are at least $k$ gatherings that not all of them were part of.

- If $k=1$, we want to know that there's nobody who was part of every gathering. Well, each person shakes hands a total of $n-1$ times, but they shake hands at least once in every gathering, so they're in at most $n-1$ gatherings (and out of at least one).
- If $2 \le k \le n-1$, then there's at most one gathering containing all $k$ people (because they can't shake hands twice), so at least $n-1$ (and therefore at least $k$) gatherings that don't contain all $k$ of them.
- If $k=n$, then there's $n$ gatherings, and no gathering contains all $n$ people.

So now we have inequalities $\|P_1\| \ge \|g_1\|$ through $\|P_n\| \ge \|g_n\|$. Well, both $\|P_1\| + \dots + \|P_n\|$ and $\|g_1\| + \dots + \|g_n\|$ count the number of pairs $(P,g)$ where person $P$ participated in gathering $g$. So the two sums are equal, and this can only happen if $\|P_i\| = \|g_i\|$ for all $i$.

Let's sort the gatherings such that $\|g_1\| \ge \dots \ge \|g_n\|$. Suppose there is a strict inequality here at some point: $\|g_i\| > \|g_{i+1}\|$. Then $\|P_{i+1}\|, \dots, \|P_n\|$ are all less than $\|g_1\|, \dots, \|g_i\|$ and so by the converse of our lemma, $P_{i+1}, \dots, P_n$ all participate in $g_1, \dots, g_i$. This results in two people participating in two gatherings together unless one of two cases holds:

- $i=1$, so $P_2, \dots, P_n$ all participate in $g_1$ together. But then $g_2$ (and all the ones after) can include at most one of $P_2, \dots, P_n$, so $\|g_2\| \le 2$, which is ruled out by the problem.
- $i=n-1$, so $P_n$ participates in all of $g_1, g_2, \dots, g_{n-1}$. But now $\|P_n\| = n-1$, and by assumption $\|P_{n-1}\| > \|P_n\|$: it must be $n$. But we've already shown that nobody can be part of all $n$ gatherings.

So we can't have $\|g_i\| > \|g_{i+1}\|$ for any $i$, which means $\|g_1\| = \dots = \|g_n\|$, which was what we wanted. (Incidentally, it also means that $\|P_1\| = \dots = \|P_n\|$.)

---

The proof above is an adaptation of the proof in [this 1948 paper by de Bruijn and Erdos](https://www.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1948-01.pdf). That paper actually analyzes this case as a side note: it shows that without the requirement that there are only $n$ gatherings, there must always be *at least* $n$.

If all gatherings have size $k$, then we have $\binom n2 = n \binom k2$, which simplifies to $n = k^2-k+1$. There are constructions where this works for many, but not all, $k$. For example:

- When $k=3$, number the people $1, 2, \dots, 7$ and take the gatherings whose participants are the sets $\{1, 2, 3\}$, $\{1,4,5\}$, $\{1,6,7\}$, $\{2,4,6\}$, $\{2,5,7\}$, $\{3,4,7\}$, $\{3,5,6\}$. This construction is known as the [Fano plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane).
- The Fano plane is a projective plane over $\mathbb F_2$, and we can generalize the construction to any finite field $\mathbb F_q$. Here, $q$ must be a prime power, and $k$ will be $q+1$.
- When $k-1$ is *not* a power of a prime, it is an open problem to show that no constructions exist. (We know that $k-1=6$ and $k-1=10$ are impossible as of 1989, and haven't managed to even deal with $k-1=12$ since then.)

Comment: Probably not to many people solved the problem.

Comment: For almost all of the steps here, there are many alternate paths, so I would not be surprised if many people in the competition found different solutions (or if some of them found shorter solutions!). De Bruijn and Erdos never used Hall's theorem, for example. I would be surprised to see a solution without some use of the lemma I started with, though.

Comment: This is a clear solution!

Comment: As an aside, once we know the first lemma, it's a "one-step" to conclude that "there must be at least n gatherings". The equality case of the problem tells us that the lemma can be strengthened to "If P is not in g, then $ ||P|| = ||g||$".

Comment: Very nice! I do wonder what is known if we relax the restriction that there are $n$ meetings [or $n' \ge n$ meetings], to there are at least $2$ meetings. This--insisting on $2$ or more meetings that is--would of course eliminate the trivial counterexample of just everyone meeting on  the first day i.e., only one meeting.

Comment: @Mike You cannot have any number of meetings that's at least $2$ but less than $n$. That's what the de Bruijn and Erdos paper proves.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to read that paper..it looks quite interesting

Comment: If we relax the connection between the number $n$ of people and the number $m$ of meetings and just take $m \ge n$, we are not guaranteed all meetings the same size after all [unless the size of each such meeting has to be $3$]. Let us come up with a meeting schedule of $m \ge n$ meetings so that every two people in an $n$-person group are in the same meeting exactly once. Then, if $1$ of the $n$ people removes himself from the group and every meeting has at least $4$ people, this meeting schedule remains valid on the remaining $n-1$ people.

Comment: Here we'd have a meeting schedule w $n-1$ people and the same number $m$ of meetings as before. The paper by DeBruijn and Erdos seems to assume additional structure, if I am understanding correctly

Comment: The paper does not assume additional structure, but we only get all meetings the same size in the $m=n$ case - and even then if we exclude a pattern where one person has one-on-one meetings with everyone else for the first $n-1$ days, and everyone else has a party without that person on the last day. (The contest problem avoids this by requiring meetings to have $\ge 3$ people, but the paper does not assume this.)